# How to write to text file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in using python. I have created a plain text file and have to encrypt it to output file. But I am getting an error as below and unable to write it to output file. The code is running but the output file which should be encrypted is created.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import binascii
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import argparse

def readfile_binary(file):
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
content = f.read()   
return content

def writefile_binary(file, content):
with open(file, 'wb') as f:
f.write(content)

def main():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Encryption and Decryption of the file')
parser.add_argument('-in', dest = 'input', required = True)
parser.add_argument('-out', dest = 'output', required = True)
parser.add_argument('-K', dest = 'key', help = 'The key to be used for encryption must be in hex')
parser.add_argument('-iv', dest = 'iv', help = 'The inintialisation vector, must be in hex')
args = parser.parse_args()

    input_content = readfile_binary(args. input)
    output_content = writefile_binary(args. output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
           main()
```

The output file should be encrypted and it should be available in the directory.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: check your formatting. Below a function or if condition etc, there should be 4 spaces or a tab. If this is not consistent, your code may not be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines:

```
input_content = readfile_binary(args. input)
output_content = writefile_binary(args. output)
```

There should not be a space in `args.input`. Here is an example,

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename')
args = parser.parse_args()

# using type hints can help reasoning about code
def write(filename: str, content: str) -> None:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(str.encode(content))

# if the filename was successfully parsed from stdin
if args.filename == 'filename.txt':
    print(f"args: {args.filename}")

    # write to the appropriate output file
    write(filename=args.filename, content="content")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to correct your code's indentation. Python requires indenting code within each function definition, loop, etc.

And as eric points out, there should be no spaces after the periods in `args. input` and `args. output`. Change those to `args.input` and `args.output` instead.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import binascii
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import argparse

def readfile_binary(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()   
        return content

def writefile_binary(file, content):
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Encryption and Decryption of the file')
    parser.add_argument('-in', dest = 'input', required = True)
    parser.add_argument('-out', dest = 'output', required = True)
    parser.add_argument('-K', dest = 'key', help = 'The key to be used for encryption must be in hex')
    parser.add_argument('-iv', dest = 'iv', help = 'The inintialisation vector, must be in hex')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    input_content = readfile_binary(args.input)
    output_content = writefile_binary(args.output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```